About Periodically Repeated Dirac Delta Potential
In the first few pages the book Solid State Physics by Giuseppe Grosso presents the equation relating the energy of a periodically repeated barrier with a barrier starting at $x=-\omega$ and ending at $x=0$, having a null potential space until $x=c$ with $b+\omega=a$ being the lattice parameter. He obtains this equation:
$$
\frac{\beta^2-q^2}{2q\beta}\sinh{\beta b}\sin{q\omega}+\cosh{\beta b}\cos{q\omega} = \cos{ka}
$$
with $\beta=\frac{2m(V_0-E)}{\hbar^2}$ and $q=\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}$.
Then it makes the limit in which $b\to0$ while preserving $V_0b$ constant. That is, turning the potential barrier into a Dirac delta potential. It gets:
$$
P\frac{\sin{qa}}{qa}+\cos{qa}=\cos{ka}
$$
with $P=\frac{mV_0ba}{\hbar^2}$.
My questions are:

As I see it, preserving $V_0b$ constant means the potential will be $V(x)=V_0b\delta(x)$. But why do I need $b$ there? My mind would tell me it is simply $V(x)=V_0\delta(x)$.

How can I get this $P$?



hint: $\delta(x)$ is a spatial density, it has dimension $1/distance$, when you let $b\to 0$ but $V_0\to\infty$ you have to keep their product, the area under the potential, a constant
